# How to set the default schema of a database in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

The following line works:

```
SELECT * FROM [myschema].users
```

But this does not:

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

A default schema is user-specific:

```
USE yourDatabase;
ALTER USER [yourUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = myschema;
```

More information about the [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) for SQL 2005 might help you as well.

As this is user-specific, if you have multiple users, you will need to execute this query (on each database) for each user whose default schema you want to update.

It is important to note:

```
The value of DEFAULT_SCHEMA is ignored if the user is a member of the sysadmin
fixed server role. All members of the sysadmin fixed server role have a default
schema of dbo.
```

Comment: Your scripts compile sucessfully but still the problem persist

Comment: @user960567 I have tested this and it worked for me. (also just tested `schema_name()`)  Did you give the default schema for the correct database? is the user you are trying to update linked to a sqlServer login?

Comment: Yes I have checked. The database is correct. The user have all permissions.

Comment: @user960567 if by 'all permissions' you mean they are in the  sysadmin fixed role, this doesn't work. `DEFAULT_SCHEMA` is ignored, and they use `dbo`

Comment: Thanks, This works for tables but not for Views. Can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: @user960567 I just added a view in my specified default_schema, tested fine.  I'll keep thinking, but it is difficult since I cannot reproduce.  Perhaps you could create a new test login & user, see what results you get with them?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the DB User has a backslash in the name. In that case, just use SQL Server Management Studio > Database > Security > Users > Properties and change the default schema there.

Comment: @ChadLehman, if you have odd characters in your user name (an NT Auth account, for example), you can always wrap the name in square brackets to ensure SQL Server handles the user name properly `[domain\ChadLehman]` as an example

Answer (score 5):

Like user960567, I tried the answers from both Adam and Ivan and could not get it working.

I was running:

```
ALTER USER myuser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=newschema
```

as suggested, but after executing this and executing

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()
```

it was still returning 'dbo' as the default schema.

To fix this I executed:

```
ALTER USER myuser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=newschema EXECUTE AS USER='myuser'
```

and it worked as expected - now executing:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()
```

returns 'newschema'.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
ALTER USER Mary51 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Purchasing;
```

To set the default schema for user.

Comment: just notice AdamWenger note [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8208124/426315) - `sysadmin` will always have `dbo` as default schema.