# I have changed default schema of a database from dbo to something else but when I wrote query it still took dbo as default schema

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-schema

**I have changed default schema of a database from dbo to something else but when I wrote query it still took dbo as default schema**

I am using Microsoft SQL server 2008 and have some problems.Please help me on this:

**I have a database which has two schemata, one is dbo and another one is studentlinkweb.**

I was logging in as *studentlinkweb*. At first, the default schema is dbo, then I had already successfully set default schema from dbo to schema studentlinkweb for the login *studentlinkweb*. (I have already checked it under

database_name>Security>Users>properties(right click)> general and

under Database>Security>Logins>loginID>properties(right click)>User Mapping)

However, when I wrote SQL script it did not work as expected. to be specific:

**I have a table names table_name under schema studentlinkweb.**

When I wrote `Select * from table_name` and ran, it returned a message: Invalid object name 'table_name'

when I wrote `Select * from studentlinkweb.table_name` and ran, the query excecuted sucessfully.

**I have another table names table_name2 under schema dbo,**

When I wrote `Select * from table_name2` and ran, the query excecuted sucessfully. . Here I didn't specify the schema but the query still ran successfully

This meant that the default schema was still dbo.

Could you please give me some idea or suggestion?

Comment: What product and/or tool were you doing this clicking with? What is the database schema? What is the data? What does "it worked" mean? We cannot read your mind. Go to StackExchange banner>help>Help Center>How do I ask a good question? and read.

Comment: Oh, so sorry. Here are the details:

Comment: Sorry philipxy, I have rewritten the question, following the guide from Help Center.

Comment: 1. Info is better. (Including the new tag.) Still, per my last comment: I didn't mean just the names of the schemas but the schemas themselves, ie their DDL for tables, constraints etc for a minimal example with your problem. What is the data? (The latter might not be necessary given your problem seems to be pre-runtime.) 2. You haven't actually asked a clear question in your question. Finally I see you put it in your title. Please put it in the body appropriately. PS have you googled "stackoverflow sql server 2008 change default schema"?

Comment: Hi Philipxy, I have googled a lot. I am quite new to this server so I am not sure about "I didn't mean just the names of the schemas but the schemas themselves, ie their DDL for tables, constraints etc for a minimal example with your problem". Could you please be clearer?

Comment: Hi. I have already found my answer in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208019/how-to-set-the-default-schema-of-a-database-in-sql-server-2005/8208124#8208124. The reason is that I had set the server role for user to be sysadmin. Therefore I could not change the default schema of the users.

Comment: It will help others if you write an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the login is set as 'sysadmin', the default schema will be fixed as dbo and cannot be changed whatsoever.