# Set dbo as default schema for all new tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, schema, create-table, owner

I have a database installed on four different production servers. Each server has its own different user. When I create a new table using create statement on these servers every server sets / prepends their user name e.g.

`Create Table tab_1 ...` will be created as
`abc.tab_1` on server_1 using `abc` as login
`def.tab_1` on server_2 using `def` as login
`ghi.tab_1` on server_3 using `ghi` as login
`jkl.tab_1` on server_4 using `jkl` as login

I want to use `dbo` as default schema and have to use following statement on every server for every new table

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER login.table_name;
```

Is there any way to modify `Create Table` statement or other setting by which every table is created on all servers as `dbo.table_name`

I am using shared hosting and there are many restrictions in SSMS, so a query based solution would be appropriate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571233/how-to-change-schema-of-all-tables-views-and-stored-procedures-in-mssql

Comment: @عجمان This link describes changing the schema after table is created and I have already mentioned it above. I am looking for setting the default schema for all new tables so that I do not have to change it later. Answer given by janschweizer is promising but I wonder can it be set even without specifying in the Create statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have control over the create table queries? In that case simply specify dbo in create:

CREATE TABLE dbo.dummy ();

For changing default schema for a user see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8208124/3480246

Comment: That's a good option. Even though, can it be set permanently or by default so that all new tables are automatically created under dbo schema without explicitly mentioning.

Comment: See my edit - you could set default schema for the users.